# Error launching emulator of the windows phone 7 Mango RC

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've been working with the Windows Phone SDK 7.0 for a long time on my computer. Now I installed the SDK 7.1 (RC) and for some reason I can't start the emulator. I'm getting this error:

> Error: The saved-state file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE{4321-43-432-432-432343234}.dess is corrupt. Please delete the corrupted saved state file and then retry.

I tried suggestions from [this article](http://blog.marktharris.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-emulator-saved-state.html). But they didn't help. Also I tried reinstalling Windows Phone SDK.

Any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: Have you deleted the file mentioned in the error message? Have you tried all the suggestions from the article?

Comment: There is no problems with the release version of SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What I'd try:

1. Open a Windows Explorer window with the file shown.
2. Delete the file.
3. Launch the emulator.
4. Wait for the error message. If there is no error message and the emulator is working, congratulations!
5. Refresh the Windows Explorer window.
6. Is the appropriate `.dess` file restored into the folder? If so, then the file that is restoring the `.dess` file is corrupt. Reinstall the SDK until it works.

### If this doesn't work, do this:

1. Figure out how your computer is different from the average developer's computer. Did you install some funky customization software? Did you mess up your registry?
2. Eliminate the differences that you can eliminate - e.g. undo any changes to the WP7 related area of your registry, find and eliminate any viruses {duh!}, kill any nonnecessary background apps like volume managers or printer software, and redownload the installer for the SDK {sometimes the installers are corrupt.}
3. Install it as a different user. This is the simple equivalent of some of the above steps.

## Remember:

- The SDK is still RC, so there may be some bugs.
- After installing the SDK for the 500th time, it may be time to try something different.
- Always install the x64 version on an x64 PC and the x86 version on an x86 PC.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I followed your suggestions but still have this issue. Seems I need to wait for release :(.

Comment: Oh well. It happens a lot with RC software- and that's why it's called 'RC'. If you like my answer, please remember to accept it.