# Error: in Windows phone7 Emulator

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

Suddenly when I start running the windows phone7 emulator it started giving me the following error, that I have showed below in the screenshot. It worked properly previousely and also didn't change any of the settings. I am using VisualStudio Express 2010 version that introduced for phone development(The IDE). I re-started the machine and checked again, but not yet any difference. Have anyone previousely experinced the same issue.

Thanks...

[image]

Comment: The answer is kind of in the question, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody else had the same Problem ;) You have to delete the File. It is also explained in this Thread [Error launching emulator of the windows phone 7 Mango RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165329/error-launching-emulator-of-the-windows-phone-7-mango-rc)

Answer (score 2):

Like the message says, just delete the file (or rename it, just in case!) and the problem should go away!

Comment: Hi Pedro Lamas, Thanks. I deleted the file and made it run the emulator. But still the error remains... Can't figure out why... May be I'll have to re install the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

go to run and type below

c:\ ProgramData\Microsoft\Xda

click enter ant delete file(which guid error give in error message).

after then its work fine.